# UIRefreshControl not Dissapearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

The pull to refresh is not disappearing. There is only 3 rows visible on the screen and after using `print(indexPath.row)` I can see that it is reloading rows 0,1,2 again but the refresh control is not disappearing.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() ... 
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.loadData), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        refreshControl!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        refreshControl!.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)...}
```

Here is the loadData function:

```
func loadData() {
    venues = [CKRecord]()

    let location = locationManager.location

    let radius = CGFloat(1000)

    let sort = CKLocationSortDescriptor(key: "Location", relativeLocation: location!)

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "distanceToLocation:fromLocation:(%K,%@) < %f", "Location", location!, radius)

    let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Venues", predicate: predicate )

    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]


    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results:[CKRecord]?, error:NSError?) in
        if let venues = results {
            self.venues = venues
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try my code your issue will be solve easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this line is wrong:

```
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)...}
```

You do not need to add a refresh control to a table view in iOS 10 as a subview. It has a `refreshControl` *property* that you *set*:

```
tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

Second, you are absolutely right that the refresh control does not disappear by itself. When you've reloaded your data, it is up to *you* to send the refresh control the `endRefreshing()` message.

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        })
```

Comment: Plus, I would strongly suggest upgrading to Xcode 8. Swift 3 is a fact. You should be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var refreshcontroller : UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

**create function .**

```
func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
        refreshcontroller.endRefreshing()
}
```

**put this line in your viewDidLoad()**

**You can also add image in UIRefreshControl**

```
refreshcontroller = UIRefreshControl()
let rcImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "refreshControl.png")!)
refreshcontroller.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string:"")
refreshcontroller.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
refreshcontroller.insertSubview(rcImageView, atIndex: 0)
self.Songlisttable.addSubview(refreshcontroller)
```